# StandardAnalyzer does not exist

Tags: java, lucene, classpath

Based on [this tutorial](http://lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) I tried to create my own basic Lucene search application. You can also use the [given example](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/code/HelloLucene.java) directly, it has no bearing on my question.

So my file `B.java` begins with:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
```

And although I have supplied the classpaths in `javac`,

```
javac -cp ~/lucene-4.10.2/core/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar
         :~/lucene-4.10.2/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar
         B.java
```

I get errors like this:

```
B.java:1: error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
```

I use the plural because this also occurs for other packages where the `.class` is inside a given JAR (checked using `unzip -l`). I assume if I can find the solution for this, it should apply for the other cases as well... what am I missing out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I seem to have found the answer.

For some reason, when including the `~` which expands to my `$HOME` directory, this makes `javac` unable to find the correct path:

```
javac -cp ~/lucene-4.10.2/core/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar
         :~/lucene-4.10.2/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar
      B.java
```

I made a soft link to the directory instead:

```
$ ln -s ~/lucene-4.10.2/ lucenepath
```

Then using the symlink, it worked:

```
javac -cp lucenepath/core/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar
         :lucenepath/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar
      B.java
```

Not sure why this is the case.